# How to load Multiple different structured CSV files into one table using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I am trying to load a set of different structured CSV files into a single table using SSIS.

I don't want to create a connection for each CSV file.

Can anyone suggest how to load a different set of structured CSV files into single table.

For Example, Patterns like

Source

> ClientDet.csv --> Id, First Name, Last Name &
> ClientPlan.csv -->Id, Plan Type, Plan Date

Destination

> dbo.ClientPlanDetails --> ID, Client Name, Plan Type, Plan Date

Comment: I've always found it best to load individual sources into their specific staging tables.   Once loaded you can perform any validations, transformations and joins necessary.

Comment: The problem is they don't want staging logic here. They are expecting to process on the fly, they need a import to direct table.

Comment: Deleting your previous question and then posting it again with a slightly different structure will get you no closer to a solution. Tagging a number of different sql server versions is also not helpful since it is highly unlikely you are not using all of them simultaneously. Nor have you made an attempt to address the issues raised previously.

Comment: _& ClientPlan.csv_ so now you have THREE files? Or is that an mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the source files have the same format, You should use a for each loop container

Comment: All CSV are different format, column will be differing for each CSV, but all CSV will be static, not dynamic.

Comment: How many different formats are there? Will this be a one time load, or will you be loading x different types of files on a schedule. You will need one for each loop for each format.... but if this is a one time load, I will suggest using the sql import, export wizard

Comment: not a one time load. its scheduled one.it is having different formats.